Use sticky and absolute CSS
I have two files. One is the layout and the other the button. The code works as intended but now the <Button /> pushes down the <SomeDiv />. To solve this I can use absolute but then my sticky does not work anymore. How to solve that my current behaviour stays the same yet the <Button /> does not push down the <SomeDiv />? The other way around I also do not want of course, i.e. <SomeDiv /> pushes down <Button />.


//layout
<div className="relative h-[100vh] w-full overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll w-[60%]">
            <main className="relative">
              <div className="sticky right-2 top-2 z-20 mr-2 flex justify-end">
                <Button />
              </div>
              <Menu />
              <SomeDiv />
              {children}
            </main>
          </div>
          
//Button
<Link href="#" className="inline-block">
      <Image />
    </Link>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Please have a look at your question and reinstate the elements I think you were telling us about - they are interpreted as HTML and so we can't see the text - e.g.. Use the {} in the editor to insert code text.

You could consider using position: fixed via the fixed class instead of sticky.


const Image = () => <img src="https://picsum.photos/24/24" width="24" height="24"/>
const SomeDiv = () => <div>SomeDiv</div>
const Menu = () => <div>Menu</div>
const Link = ({ ...props, children }) => <a {...props}>children</a>

function Button() {
  return (
    <Link href="#" className="inline-block">
      <Image />
    </Link>
  );
}

function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <div className="relative h-[100vh] w-full overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-scroll w-[60%]">
      <main className="relative">
        <div className="fixed right-2 top-2 z-20 mr-2 flex justify-end">
          <Button />
        </div>
        <Menu />
        <SomeDiv />
        {children}
       </main>
     </div>
  );
}
    
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <Layout>
    <div class="h-[200vh]"></div>
  </Layout>
);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-QVs8Lo43F9lSuBykadDb0oSXDL/BbZ588urWVCRwSIoewQv/Ewg1f84mK3U790bZ0FfhFa1YSQUmIhG+pIRKeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-6a1107rTlA4gYpgHAqbwLAtxmWipBdJFcq8y5S/aTge3Bp+VAklABm2LO+Kg51vOWR9JMZq1Ovjl5tpluNpTeQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div id="app"></div>



fixed acts like a combination of sticky and absolute, as per the MDN documentation:

The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its initial containing block, which is the viewport in the case of visual media. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

